# Pwm output of a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

How the pwm output of a microcontroller reduces the power delivery to a load? I understand that pwm is used to reduce power to a load but can't this be done with the normal digital output of the microcontroller? For example, in my application, I'm giving the pwm output of a microcontroller to a high side switch to switch it on, that is connect to a heater (load, in my application)?

Comment: It does not reduce anything. It helps to control it, perhaps...

Comment: If you pass the PWM through a low-pass filter you reduce the voltage. Is this what you're asking? If so, it's as simple as it being on longer than it's off. The average output voltage is directly related to the ratio of on-time to off-time. You can do that simply with the digital output of the microcontroller but you have to manually adjust the pulse widths. Using the PWM module makes that easier.

Comment: Please clarify the claim "reduces the power delivery" (maybe add references and citations; use the citation formatting). If you're asking whether or not there's a difference between the PWM functionality of a microcontroller vs. "bit banging" a GPIO output manually to create PWM please emphasis on that. Downvoted until clarified.

Answer (score 4):

You have a heater, it is on 100% of the time but suppose that is too much, it generates to much heat.

As a solution you switch it off for 10 seconds and then on for 10 seconds and then off again for 10 seconds ... so effectively you'd be using it at half of the maximum power right? Instead of you switching the heater on and off you could use a microcontroller.

Since the microcontroller is much faster than a human you have a choice. You could program the micro to switch on/off every 10 seconds **or** you could do it much faster, for example 100 times per second. That's 1000x faster. That fast switching is basically what PWM does. It switches so fast that you get an average value as a result.

For a large (room) heater switching every 10 seconds would be fine. There is no need to switch any faster. It would be different when you have a very small heater for some lab experiment.

Also imagine instead of a heater, you want to control a lamp. Switching it on/off every 10 seconds would drive a human crazy. Do that more than 100 times per second and humans cannot notice it.

So you're right, you don't need the PWM function, you can achieve the same by making a program that controls the switching for you. PWM is just there for convenience to control lights where the switching speed needs to be such that humans cannot detect it.

Answer (score 1):

Pulse-width modulation (PWM) is the process of modulating the duty cycle of a signal, used in this application to control the average power sent to the load.

So if the pulse is on for 10% of the time and off for 90% of the time you will have 1/10 of the power. So you are playing with the proportion between on-time and off-time.

Ref.: http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/PWM_Modulation/